# functional equation of $\zeta_X(s)$ in various settings

Tags: zeta-functions

Say we have a set $X$ :

- with a norm (possibly twisted by a character) and an unique factorization 
  $$\zeta_X(s) = \sum_{x \in X} |x|^{-s} = \prod_{P \in X} \frac{1}{1-|P|^{-s}}$$
- from some additive properties of $X$ we have a functional equation  $$\zeta_X(s)= \chi(s) \zeta_X(n-s)$$

$X$ can be many different objects : [the integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), [a ring of integers of a number field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_zeta_function), the [effective divisors of a function field](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2014/2014EllenbergNotes.pdf), of a [curve over a finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures#Statement_of_the_Weil_conjectures), the Hecke eigenvalues of a [modular/automorphic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_form)...

**My question** : Is something like the Poisson summation formula in the adelic setting what I need for unifying the derivation of a functional equation in all these cases ?

Comment: similar to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122442/functional-equations-of-zeta-functions-over-global-fields and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94165/analogues-of-the-riemann-roch-theorem/94192#94192

Comment: This question is a bit vague. How about this: for an elliptic curve over a number field, we can define the $L$-function in the way you say, and we can *conjecture* that there's a functional equation but we can't prove it in general, so in this case it somehow doesn't make sense to ask if there is a Poisson summation formula because nobody knows. So probably we have to restrict to cases where the fnl eqn _is_ known. But then pretty much every case is subsumed by the automorphic forms case by Langlands so what you need is nothing more than the proof of fnl eqn for autom L-fns (Godement-Jacquet).

Comment: @KevinBuzzard I know quite well the usual L-functions, but I discovered the function field ones quite recently, and I have no idea how to link automorphic forms with function fields and Weil's conjecture. I'd like a (conjectural is not a problem) way to unify what properties of $X$ makes the zeta function suitable for a functional equation.

Comment: My answer to the question of how to "unify what properties of $X$ makes the zeta function suitable for a functional equation" is that $X$ has to be motivic in nature, and then the Langlands philosophy says that it is automorphic, and the functional equation is because of Godement-Jacquet, which generalises Tate's thesis, which does indeed use Poisson summation adelically.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Is there a more intuitive (possibly less general) version of "being motivic"  ? What is the key property we want ?

Comment: I think the key property we want is being automorphic. I am not sure I know an example of a family of $L$-functions which have analytic/meromorphic continuation and which are not automorphic. I would argue that the analytic continuation of $\sum a_n/n^s$ is an extremely subtle property for a collection of integers $a_1,a_2,a_3,...$ to have, it is a very delicate symmetry, and the theory of automorphic forms seems to isolate this symmetry precisely (because of converse theorems, for example).

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Yes, for example I have no problem with the fact that the Mellin transform of an automorphic form is a Dirichlet series with a functional equation as in the Selberg class. But I'm asking on the algebraic side, when we start from the the zeta function of some algebraic structure.

Comment: Now maybe answering that *this is the point of the Langland program/conjectures to define those algebraic structures having a nice zeta function (Euler product and functional equation)* is the answer I wanted. And so looking at "[automorphic over local fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Langlands_conjectures#Local_Langlands_conjectures_for_GL2)" (and function fields) would be a good start.

Comment: So the general philosophy is that the automorphic $L$-functions which arise from some algebraic setting should be the algebraic ones, which should be the ones coming from motives. So on the algebraic side you should be looking for structures which e.g. give rise to some Galois representstion for which the $L$-function is the associated $L$-function of this representation. I'm sorry I can't do any better, I think your question is a very "big picture" question and my answer is "they have to be motivic", so if you believe Langlands "they have to be automorphic".